# RoR memory management within request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are facing some memory issues with HTTP requests and was asked to do pagination in our clients. As a client side developer I would like to understand if the pagination could be internally handled inside our Ruby on Rails server because our case is that all results are always fetched.

Could someone explain the memory handling of RoR in following cases:

**5000 items queried in one request**

**5000 items queried in 5 requests, (1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)**

Thanks.

Comment: Not a direct answer but: You don't need to fetch all results the first time. Use `will_paginate` to easily execute individual queries for each page server-side.

Comment: Or `kaminari`, just a matter of favor : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use server side pagination, because when a request is completed, the objects allocated during the processing of that request become garbage, and will be garbage collected at some time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use server side pagination with an offset parameter in your http request that would be used to populate the offset of a limited ActiveRecord query. If you post some code or further information I can give you a more specific example.

Comment: So does server side pagination free memory within the requests context?

Comment: Not instantly but the objects allocated in one request become garbage after that request is completed.

Comment: I believe that is the problem and client side paging is wanted to get more GC cycles. So I wondered if there is some mechanism in RoR itself to keep memory in balance and paginate the request on the server.

Comment: If you use unicorn as your application server, and do want a GC after each request, then take a look at section 2.3.2 of https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/performance